# Deserialize collection type virtual data member

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer, datamember

I'm trying to deserialize json to `RequestWithDefault` object

JSON:

```
{
  "fields":["f1","f2"]
}
```

My simple class diagram:

```
[DataContext]
public abstract class BaseRequest
{
  [DataMember]
  public virtual List<string> Fields { get; set; }
}

[DataContext]
public class RequestWithDefault : BaseRequest
{
  [DataMember]
  public override List<string> Fields {get; set; } = new List<string> {"test"}
}
```

After deserializing json to `RequestWithDefault` object `Fields` property contains `["test", "f1", "f1"]`. I want to be sure that this default values are applied only in case when `Fields` were not specified in request, or was specified as null. How I can do this? I tried with `[OnDeserializing]` attribute but without success. Result is the same

According to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/collection-types-in-data-contracts
Looks like during deserialization `DataContractSerializer` calling `Add` method from collection. That's why I have also default value and rest of items are added. When I will replace `List<string>` to `string[]` everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems WCF serialization never use setter to set the value of the `DataMember` with type of collection, but use `Add` instead. Because of this, the only way to check whether the `fields` has any value is to check after it has been deserialized (not while deserializing).

```
[DataContext]
public abstract class BaseRequest
{
  [DataMember]
  public virtual List<string> Fields { get; set; }
}

[DataContext]
public class RequestWithDefault : BaseRequest
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext c)
    {
        if (Fields == null
            || Fields.Count < 1)
        {
            Fields = new List<string> { "test" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow if I'm implementing this in that way setter is never called. I'm always getting default value.

Comment: @Emil I've updated my answer to reflect based on your comments, I hope this one works for you.

Comment: It should work. I was thinking about this solution after I found that Serializer not calling setters at all. I will create some protected method to set defaults. Thanks